UML subsets of ordered supersets
Some properties are defined as subsets of inherited properties with the {ordered} constraint, for example:  RedefinableTemplateParameter::/inheritedParameter subsets TemplateSignature::parameter (see p. 196 and p. 99 of the PDF file for the UML 2.5.1 specification). The latter is {ordered}, but the subset is not defined as ordered.
In fact, the OCL implementation given for the derived property RedefinableTemplateParameter::/inheritedParameter is as follows:
inheritedParameter() : TemplateParameter [0..*]
Derivation for RedefinableTemplateSignature::/inheritedParameter

body: if extendedSignature->isEmpty() then Set{} else extendedSignature.parameter->asSet()
endif

Perhaps the inherited property does not need to be ordered? Or is it implicitly assumed that the ordering of the superset would carry over to the subset?

A subset of an ordered set does not need to be ordered.
The set of people in a waiting queue is ordered. But the subset of the people in this queue wearing a hat is not ordered.
The fact that one set is a subset doesn't have any influence on the ordering. It is even possible, that the subset has a different ordering.
There is an exception: If the superset is defined as a union of the subsets (isDerivedUnion), then the subsets must be ordered, since the superset doesn't have any direct content. In fact the UML contains 5 cases where this rule is violated. I think this is a minor bug.
inheritedParameter however, is not one of these cases. The ordered set TemplateSignature::Parameter is not derived. The reason why inheritedParameter is not ordered is probably, because extendedSignature is not ordered. So, the derivation can in general not come up with an order of the inherited parameters (in the context of templates). Of course, this could be solved by defining an order, but then, for what purpose? There is no specific semantics for the order of TemplateParameters. It is convenient for the modeler to define them in an order which is preserved. That doesn't apply to a derived property.
I only found three places in the specification, where the order does carry some meaning:

the ordering of the union is defined by evaluating the subsetting properties in the order in which they appear in the result of allAttributes()


Lifeline::events[*] {ordered}


The argument Pins of a CallAction are matched, in order, to the sublist of input Parameters,...

Please note, that the parameters mentioned here are not TemplateSignature::parameter but rather Operation::ownedParameter and Behavior::ownedParameter,

Thank you, Axel, for this very precise answer. It addresses the original question and also my fundamental doubts about ordering (or not).

You probe too far into the dark corners. You must remember that the UML specification is a best endeavors comprise by a well-intentioned committee with limited tool support.
Amongst other things UML allows you to draw pretty pictures of model-oriented C++ or Java systems. Since invocation of super is a programmer discretion, observance of the Liskov Substitution Principle is a design choice and so UML must support that choice. (A clean modelling language would not have private/protected/public which are ignored by OCL at analysis time. Rather they should be code generator markups.)
LSP would dictate that subsetting an ordered/unique feature must yield a correspondingly ordered/unique derived feature since invoking the super-accessor should return the super typing. But in a non-LSP world the super-accessor may not exist or maybe the implementor just wants to prohibit users exploiting ordered/unique or has strange multiple-inheritance aspects.
The situation gets much worse with redefines where things really can change incompatibly. The original intention of redefines seems to have been to manually 'implement' an overloading algorithm for the UML metamodel. However for user models, UML specifies that OCL specifies overloading and correspondingly, OCL specifies that UML specifies overloading. Nonetheless the flexibility of redefines allows modellers to create completely unintelligible/unimplementable designs.
For your specific example the spelling of parameter rather than the more consistent ownedParameters may have confused the author into thinking there is just one and so ordered is irrelevant.

Thank you, Ed. I take it that you agree that having an ordered superset implies that any subset of it should also be ordered, even without an explicit constraint? (RE: spelling of multivalued properties with singular forms (i.e. "parameter" and not "parameters"): if I had anything to say about it, I would use plural forms for all names of functions and multivalued queries which imply that some kind of collection, possibly empty, will be returned. But I wasn't asked. ;) I know there are different philosophies about it, though.)

I agree that in a clean modeling paradigm unique/ordered would propagate to derived features. But UML has the flexibility to support dirty modeling so no I don't agree.

In the meantime I realize that I do not understand what using the dot operator means in extendedSignature.parameter because extendedSignature is also multivalued. As written, does this mean that a union is formed of all parameters for each extendedSignature, then returned as a Set? Please let me know if I should create another question about this instead of asking it here.

The dot operator when applied to collection is an implicit collect. This makes for compact OCL that is often confusing to read. extendedSignature->collect(parameter) is clearer. collect of course loses uniqueness and ordering.
